# Don't understand why the result is an empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created 2 empty lists and wanted to combine them in a dictionary. However when I print it, it shows an empty dictionary. The output is shown below, too.

```
def game():
    empt_list=[]
    empt_list_meaning=[]
    empt_dict = dict(zip(empt_list, empt_list_meaning))
    a_options = input("Please select one of these options: ")
    if a_options == 1:
        a_newword = raw_input("What word you want to add? ")
        empt_list.append(a_newword)
        a_newword_meaning=raw_input("add the meaning of the word: ")
        empt_list_meaning.append(a_newword_meaning)
    elif a_options==2:
        print(empt_dict)

    print ("would you like to continue or exit?\n1.contine\n2.exit")
    now = input(">>> ")
    if now == 1:
        game()
    else:
        print "bye"

game()
```

Here is the output:

```
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? umer
add the meaning of the word: name
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? qwe
add the meaning of the word: asd
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 2
{}
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>>
```

Comment: You have intialized `empt_dict = dict(zip(empt_list, empt_list_meaning))` in the begenning of your function but you never add elements to it .. So, obviously it'll be empty.

Comment: @ChihebNexus i did put also on elif part but it didnt change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run `game()` recursively in your program, meaning that every time someone types in "1" (for continue), `game()` is run.

In `game()`, the first thing that is run is to empty the lists `empt_list` and `empt_list_meaning`.

```
empt_list=[]
empt_list_meaning=[]
```

However, everytime someone types in 1, the dictionaries are emptied.

One way to fix, making `empt_list` and `empt_list_meaning` global variables:

```
empt_list=[]
empt_list_meaning=[]
def game():
        global empt_list, empt_list_meaning
        empt_dict = dict(zip(empt_list, empt_list_meaning))
        a_options = input("Please select one of these options: ")
        if a_options == 1:
            a_newword = str(raw_input("What word you want to add? "))
            empt_list.append(a_newword)
            a_newword_meaning=str(raw_input("add the meaning of the word: "))
            empt_list_meaning.append(a_newword_meaning)
        elif a_options==2:
            print(empt_dict)

        print ("would you like to continue or exit?\n1.contine\n2.exit")
        now = input(">>> ")
        if now == 1:
            game()
        else:
            print "bye"

game()
```

Output:

```
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? sldf
add the meaning of the word: lkj
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 1
What word you want to add? sld
add the meaning of the word: oisdf
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 1
Please select one of these options: 2
{'sld': 'oisdf', 'sldf': 'lkj'}
would you like to continue or exit?
1.contine
2.exit
>>> 2
bye
```

Comment: Global variables are variables that are accessible throughout the program and not just in the method